# Problems with user comments

Tags: comments, comment-form

I'm currently running EE ver 2.7.3 and can not get user comments to function properly.

Issue 1:

Comment form returns to an empty template. Upon submitting a comment, the returned page only displays my page top, widgets section, and footer. The page header and body are output with nothing inside the "entries" tags. (the wrappers are there, just no content). This only happens when I submit a test comment when "logged out". If I am logged in the form submits normally and I am returned to the page and everything is normal.

I tried using an EECore test site to trouble shoot with but that won't even display the comment submission form. I have verified that commenting is enabled in both the channel prefs as well as the post options and comments are allowed for non-members.

Issue 2:

Both the ce_gravitar and gravitar plugins only display my gravitar (i've tried both separately). I have even created a test template thats totally flat (no snippets, embeds, or globals) thinking it was a parsing issue but no luck.

P.S. I tried using the code tage to embed my template here for review but it didn't work so I deleted it...